# SAP software to Excel - Macro doesn't paste the values in a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

can someone check the code below and tell if I'm missing something or there is another way to make this work?

To sumup: I've created a Macro that connects with SAP Software, starts a Loop getting data from a table, pastes in excel and goes to the other account until the loop ends.

I've extracted a script from SAP software to get the values from a table displayed at the end of MB5L transaction.

the code at the end loops to get data from accounts, paste the values in a tab named "temp", formats it, copy the data in a tab named base a goes to another account.

In the below block the command `Application.SendKeys "^v", True` the data is not pasted:

```
        thisworkbook.Sheets("temp").Activate
        Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
        Range("A1").Select
        Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
        Application.SendKeys "^v", True
        Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
```

If instead of this block I use the command `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Paste`, the data comes wrong.

Full code below:

```
Sub MB5L()
    Dim appl, SapGuiAuto, Connection, session, WScript
    Dim i As Integer

    Set rawben = Sheets("Base")
    lastRow = rawben.Cells(Rows.Count, "AK").End(xlUp).Row
       
    thisworkbook.Sheets("base").Select


' this block checks connection with SAP software
    If Not IsObject(appl) Then
       Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
       Set appl = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    End If
    If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
       Set Connection = appl.Children(0)
    End If
    If Not IsObject(session) Then
       Set session = Connection.Children(0)
    End If
    If IsObject(WScript) Then
       WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
       WScript.ConnectObject appl, "on"
    End If
    
    
            On Error Resume Next
            For i = 1 To 30
                session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 3 'press f3 until it gets in homepage
                session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 12 'press f12 until it gets in homepage
                session.findById("wnd[1]").Close
            Next i
            On Error GoTo 0
    
    session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 2 To lastRow 'loop to get the account number
        If Not rawben.Range("AK" & i).Value <> "" Then Exit For

        session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "MB5L" ' access transaction
        session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/radVMSALDO").Select
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtBUKRS-LOW").Text = "0001" 'company code
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSKONT-LOW").Text = rawben.Range("AK" & i).Value 'types the account
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/radVMSALDO").SetFocus
        session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[12,5]").SetFocus
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[12,5]").caretPosition = 9
        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 2
        session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[1]/menu[2]").Select 'selects saving mode and pops up a window
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_STEPLOOP:SAPLSPO5:0150/sub:SAPLSPO5:0150/radSPOPLI-SELFLAG[4,0]").Select 'selects the "save in clipboard option
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_STEPLOOP:SAPLSPO5:0150/sub:SAPLSPO5:0150/radSPOPLI-SELFLAG[4,0]").SetFocus
        session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press 'hits the button to save in clipboard
        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 3 'press f3 to go back 1 page
        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 3 'press f3 to go back 1 page
        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 3 'press f3 to go back 1 page
            

        thisworkbook.Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
        thisworkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "temp" 'adds a new tab to paste and format values
        Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
        thisworkbook.Sheets("temp").Activate
        Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
        Range("A1").Select
        Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
        Application.SendKeys "^v", True
        Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
                               

        If Range("b2").Characters.Count = 0 Then 'checks the content of cell B2, if it matches the criteria the next step will be a "text to columns"
                Columns("A:A").Select
                Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
                    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
                    :="|", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, _
                    1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12 _
                    , 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
                Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
                Rows("1:1").Delete
                Rows("2:2").Delete
                Columns("A:A").Delete
            
        Else 'if the previous criteria is no true then the next step is to delete rows and columns
                    
                Rows("1:1").Delete
                Rows("2:2").Delete
                Columns("A:A").Delete
            
        End If
                    
        Dim nextLine: nextLine = thisworkbook.Sheets("base").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'this block is to get the values and move to another tab _
    right below the previous line with values
                    
        Sheets("temp").Select
        Rows("2:2").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy
                    
        thisworkbook.Sheets("base").Range("A" & nextLine).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        thisworkbook.Sheets("base").Range("A" & nextLine).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                    
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        thisworkbook.Sheets("temp").Delete

    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0

'Message at the ending of the extraction
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Extraction complete", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain the exact symptom corresponding to "comes wrong": what are the exact contents of the clipboard, what you get after pasting and what you expect. Thank you. I also recommend to [keep your code to the minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as the SAP GUI part is not needed, the question can start from the situation of having given data in clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Code that I have used to eliminate copy/paste. This code instead casts the information from a grid table in SAP to and excel spreadsheet.

```
Sub Get_Report(RSh As Worksheet, session As Object)
Dim RepoArr() As Variant
Dim columns As Object
Set myGrid = session.findbyID("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell")

arows = myGrid.RowCount - 1
acols = myGrid.ColumnCount - 1
ReDim RepoArr(0 To arows, 0 To acols) As Variant
Set columns = myGrid.ColumnOrder

For j = 0 To arows
    myGrid.firstVisibleRow = j
    For i = 0 To acols
        RepoArr(j, i) = myGrid.GetCellValue(j, columns(i))
    Next i
Next j
RSh.Range("A3").Resize(UBound(RepoArr, 1) + 1, UBound(RepoArr, 2) + 1).Value = RepoArr
End Sub
```